# Creating an alternating list of arrays with a loop in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to generate an alternating list of arrays with a loop, but I can't figure out the syntax. Currently I'm using the following code (as an example):

```
[ numpy.array([i,4,5]),numpy.array([31,4,i]) for i in range(5)) ]
```

It gives the following error:

> "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

I've tried `,` `+` and `concatenate` but it doesn't seem to work.

The desired output is the following list with alternating array entries:

```
[array([0, 4, 5]),
 array([31,  4,  0]),
 array([1, 4, 5]),
 array([31,  4,  1]),
 array([2, 4, 5]),
 array([31,  4,  2]),
 array([3, 4, 5]),
 array([31,  4,  3]),
 array([4, 4, 5]),
 array([31,  4,  4])]
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You've got to show us your expected output ...

Comment: I think I have what you wanted. Did I guess the right output?

Comment: Yeah that's it, thanks a lot! Sorry for the confusion, I'll adjust the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably no easy way to get around making a list of list of arrays, so using `sum` to add all the internal lists together to get one list of arrays. (see documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum))

```
In [6]: sum([ [numpy.array([i,4,5]), numpy.array([31,4,i])] for i in range(5) ],[])
Out[6]: 
[array([0, 4, 5]),
 array([31,  4,  0]),
 array([1, 4, 5]),
 array([31,  4,  1]),
 array([2, 4, 5]),
 array([31,  4,  2]),
 array([3, 4, 5]),
 array([31,  4,  3]),
 array([4, 4, 5]),
 array([31,  4,  4])]
```

Comment: Cool. Can you edit your question to provide an example of the output you wanted?

Answer (score 4):

What do you want to produce?

```
In [3]: [ (numpy.array([i,4,5]),numpy.array([31,4,i])) for i in range(5) ]
Out[3]:
[(array([0, 4, 5]), array([31,  4,  0])),
 (array([1, 4, 5]), array([31,  4,  1])),
 (array([2, 4, 5]), array([31,  4,  2])),
 (array([3, 4, 5]), array([31,  4,  3])),
 (array([4, 4, 5]), array([31,  4,  4]))]
```

Using a for loop, the same thing:

```
myList = []
for i in range(5):
   item = ( numpy.array([i,4,5]),numpy.array([31,4,i]) )
   myList.append(item)
print(myList)
```

Comment: Yeah exactly! They should alternate in the list. When I use + instead of , btw, it returns this:

[array([31,  8,  5]),
 array([32,  8,  6]),
 array([33,  8,  7]),
 array([34,  8,  8]),
 array([35,  8,  9])]

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to get the result without the brackets, so just as list with the items being the arrays, is that also possible?

Comment: @fransheg Can you please edit the original question and write down the exact expected output? I am not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I've now added the desired output. The question is now solved in the answer of NightShadeQueen, thanks again.